# Зависание эмулятора genemotion после запуска

Tags: android, virtualbox

Может у кого было,я решения не нашел,только связанные с виртуалбоксом,но они не подходят.
При старте виртуального устройства оно запускается быстро но после запуска висит еще минуты 2.
Что я делал:
переустановка эмулятора+виртуалбокс
чистка реестра+система
антивирус-добовил в довер. зону
[image: Курсора на скрине не видно,но перемещать эмулятор я не могу по экрану и курсор мыши ввиде значка песочных часов]
Прикрепляю логи работы устройства:
http://pastebin.com/MFRXGeNC    -устройство
Какие еще нужны логи из этого списка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Так выкинь его и все. После обновления родные телефоны стали нормально работать. Я ими стал пользоваться. Ни чего не виснет, все быстро летает, хотя у меня машина не самая мощная.

Comment: можно,но хотелось бы иначе